# Possible to change VTY password 7 to secret 9

Tags: cisco

The version I have

```
Router1#sh ver
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 16.09.02
```

.

```
Router1#sh run | sec vty
line vty 0 4
 password 7 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 login authentication local_auth
 transport input telnet ssh
```

When I'm in the conf mode of the vty line. It doesn't give me an option for `algorithm-type scrypt` The following is the only options I get.

```
Router1(config-line)#password ?
  0      Specifies an UNENCRYPTED password will follow
  7      Specifies a HIDDEN password will follow
  <0-9>  Encryption types not explicitly specified
  LINE   The UNENCRYPTED (cleartext) line password
  LINE   The UNENCRYPTED (cleartext) line password

Router1(config-line)#password 9 ?
  LINE  The UNENCRYPTED (cleartext) line password

Router1(config-line)#password 9
```

My question is, does a method exist to improve the vty security from password 7 to secret 9

Thanks in advance

P.S what does `<0-9>  Encryption types not explicitly specified` mean?

Comment: This depends on the ios version. You can look up the command online for your specific version.

Comment: I have 16.09.02, anyway to word it to look it up?

Comment: If it will take anything other than "0" and "7", it supports encrypted passwords. You'll have to look up what exactly each number means ([ios 15.7] md5 = 5, sha256 = 8, scrypt = 9)

Comment: Right @RickyBeam i'm looking to see if VTY can be set to scrypt unless that is not possible. I'm using an ASR 1001-X IOS 16.09.02